# Poker problem: Find the probability you are dealt 2 hole cards that can FLOP a straight.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poker

My brute force approach:

We notice that some ranks have more "straight feasibility" than other ranks. An ace has a range of $8$ potential 2nd cards $\{2-5, 10-K\}$, whereas a $2$ has a range of only $5$ potential $2$nd cards $\{A, 3-6\}$.

There are $7$ ranks that have a range of $8: \{A, 5-10\}$. That leaves $6$ ranks left: $2-4$ and $J-K$. We notice again that these $6$ ranks can form $3$ pairs: $2-K$ has a range of $5, 3-Q$ range is $6$, and $4-J$ range is $7$

If $1$st card in $\{A, 5 -> 10\}$, range $r = 8$.

The remaining cards are paired:
$$
\begin{align}
2 - K: r &= 5 \\
3 - Q: r &= 6 \\
4 - J: r &= 7
\end{align}
$$
Applying the Law of Total Probability:

$$P = \frac{7\cdot4}{52} \cdot \frac{8\cdot4}{51} + \frac{8}{52} \cdot \frac{4}{51}(5 + 6 + 7)$$

- $7\cdot4/52$: $P$ (first card in $\{A, 5-10\}$)
- $8\cdot4/51$: Range has $8$ ranks, each rank can have $4$ suits, multiplied together to get the number of $2$nd cards that would satisfy our condition
- $8/52$: $P$ (first card is a "paired" card: $2-4$ or $J-K$)
- $4/51$: potential suits for the rank of the $2$nd card.
- $5, 6, 7$: respective range $r$ of $2$nd card for each pairs

$P = 55.5$%

Is the answer correct? Is there a more elegant / less algebra-extensive approach?

Thank you!

Comment: That is good working. I would suggest consider there are $14$ ranks instead of $13$. $A$ appears twice, once on the left and once on the right. Now you have complete symmetry with $6$ ranks in the middle that have $8$ possibilities and then it reduces by $1$ each going left or going right. That is $6 \cdot 8 + 2 \cdot (7 + 6 + 5 + 4) = 92$ possibilities to choose $2$ ranks. So the answer is $\frac{92 \cdot 4^2}{52 \cdot 51}$.

Comment: @MathLover Hah that's much more elegant than mine. There's definitely a ton of symmetry in card problem and that's definitely the way to go. Thank you - I got some great insights! Cheers.